# respond to .html extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

I am moving a website from a static website to MVC 5. I need to create controllers/actions to respond to requests with old URLs. ( and return a redirect, page moved ) If I just hardcode the old URL in attribute routing, I get

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

What is the best way of approaching this. ( what I mean is that how could I make a route for a url with .html extension, and ASP.net respond to it)
I think right now IIS sees that .html and tries to send the file to the client without going through the application. How could I remove that behavior on a shared hosting ?

the html files that are being served right now are in different folders.

example:

I need to map this URL to a controller/action:

```
example.com/services/Renovations.html
```

we will be mapping it to controller => services , and action => renovations

```
example.com/contactus.html
```

we will be mapping it to controller => contact , and action => index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your application using MVC Controllers/Actions as appropriate for your new architecture, then implement a set of [URL Rewrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) rules at the IIS level to map the old URL's to new ones. The Rewrite rules will be stored inside your `web.config` file which is handy for moving the configuration from Dev to Staging to Live environments.

If you give some examples of your old URL's and their new corresponding routes, I could give you some sample IIS Rewrite rules to match. This works best if your old URL's followed a pattern, e.g. `/products/{skucode}.html` etc

**EDIT:** Some sample rewrite rules to match the requested redirects.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <clear />
      <rule name="Static rewrites" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true" >
        <match url="^(.*?\.html)$" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="{static site rewrites:{R:1}}" appendQueryString="true" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
    <rewriteMaps>
      <rewriteMap name="Static site rewrites" ignoreCase="true">
        <add key="contact.html" value="contact" />
        <add key="services/renovations.html" value="services/renovations" />
      </rewriteMap>
    </rewriteMaps>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It should be clear how to add more keys to the `rewriteMap` for other pages you'd like redirected. To clarify, these are Redirects and will return `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` response codes to the browser and transparently redirect it to the new route.

Comment: Thank you @tianvh ,
for example two of the routes that I want to change are:
/Services/Renovation.html    to  /Services/Renovation
/Contact.html     to   /Contact

Comment: @BenjaminWeblySpeaking.ca I've edited my answer to address those examples.

Comment: Thank for the clarification. I was actually going to redirect to a controller and then implement 301 redirect.

Comment: Doing it at the IIS level makes it easy to change if you'd rather do URL Rewrite instead of Redirect. This way your clients will still see `contact.html` in their address bar but now get the content from the new MVC controllers. To do this, simply change the `rule` to `<action type="Rewrite" ...`

Comment: the rules you mentioned worked perfectly on our dev servers. the only issue we  ran into was that our client is running on a shared hosting and they wont allow wildcard redirect. so I had to write the rules for each page. luckily we only had 7 pages to rewrite. here is an example of one rule, that I used and it worked.
example
`<rule name="AboutRedirect" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^aboutus.html$"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/AboutUs" />
        </rule>`